# Is WebStorage my best alternative?

Tags: javascript, html

So, i have a  tag that i want to fill with text. This text will be the same on several pages, and i want the ability to make changes to this text without editing every page individually.

I can do this with a javascript and WebStorage, but it doesnt seem like the best solution for this. Is there any other way i can do this?

I would like to avoid having to use an sql server for this. See my working code in a fiddle below.

working code:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("11", "some text1");
    localStorage.setItem("22", "some text2");
    // Retrieve
    localStorage.setItem("33", "some text3");
    localStorage.setItem("44", "some text4");    



    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("11");
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("22");
    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("33");
    document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("44");
} else {
    document.getElementById("topptur").innerHTML = "Web Storage er ikke støttet, last ned nyeste versjon av nettleseren din";
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erlendvo/00qag44b/1/)

Comment: Why it doesn't seems to be the best way ?

Comment: @bhansa There is quite a bit of text to be stored, and it seems to me that the javascript would become rather large. Do you have any other options?

Comment: *"i want the ability to make changes to this text without entering every page individually"* Do you mean editing the pages, or *using* the pages?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder entering and editing, should have written editing, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that web storage isn't a good solution for this.

You have at *least* a couple of options:

1. A [server-side include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) (a file where you define that text, and then include it in all the pages using a server-side mechanism)
2. A single JavaScript file that you link to on all pages that will fill in the text you want
3. At some point you'll be able to do [HTML imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/) client-side, but there isn't robust support for it yet

For instance, your JS file might be:

```
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "the text for 1";
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "the text for 2";
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "the text for 3";
document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "the text for 4";
```

...and then you'd include it just after the last of those elements in the pages where you want that content. If you want the content to change, just change it in the JS file.

In general, #1 is probably the better option, at least until #3 becomes more viable.

Comment: a follow up question. As i use this, the div will only be populated by the first line in the JS. If i use id="4" i get no result. Check out the fiddle, and try to change the ID to 1. Then it works...[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erlendvo/00qag44b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the same text for all the files, you can have these ways

- Creating a common json and reading the data from it, edit it anytime.
- Using [Javascript Templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates)

You can your data in a template and can use it anywhere in the project, this seems to a better option here.